# Rational functions on reduced complex varieties that extend to global holomorphic functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $A$ is an integral domain and a finite type $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Let $X := \text{Spec}(A)$ and $K := \text{Frac}(A)$ be the fraction field. Suppose $h \in K$ is a rational function that extends to a global complex analytic function on  $X(\mathbb{C}).$ Can we conclude that $h \in A$?

If $A$ is integrally closed then, (it seems to me that) just the fact that $h$ extends *continuously* to $X(\mathbb{C})$ suffices to conclude that $h \in A$ and if $A$ is not necessarily normal, I realize that a continuous global extension is not sufficient to draw the required conclusion. Hence I'm interested in what happens in the absence of normality/regularity hypotheses and when we additionally require a *holomorphic* global extension?

Comment: I am guessing that we embed $X$ into $\mathbb{C}^n$ by choosing generators for $A$ and then the definition of "holomorphic"on $X$ is "restriction of a holomorphic function from $\mathbb{C}^n$"?

Comment: Maybe the following works?
Let $\phi$ be a holomorphic function on $X^{an}$. The assumption is that for some dense open affine subset $U\subset X$, we have that $\phi|_U = g^{an}/h^{an}$, where $g$ and $h$ are regular functions on $X=Spec A$ (with no common factors say). Note that this implies that $h \phi - g$ is a holomorphic function which is the zero function on $U$. Now you use that $A$ is an integral domain (or $X$ is an integral scheme) to say that $h\phi - g =0$ on $X$.  We conclude that $\phi = g/h$ on $X$. This then forces $\phi$ to be regular.

Comment: Side comment: You might be interested in knowing that $A$ is integrally closed in  the ring of (global) holomorphic functions $\mathcal{H}(X^{an})$ on $X^{an}$; see for instance Prop. 2.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09338.pdf

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thank you for your comment! It seems that your argument works for `\phi` merely continuous, which shouldn't be the case. Maybe I don't follow the final step - so once we know `h \phi - g = 0` in the fraction field  `K` how do we conclude that `\phi \in A`? The result about integral closedness in the ring of analytic functions is very interesting, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer The definition of holomorphic I had in mind was just that $h$ is a global section of the structure sheaf of the complex analytification $X^\text{an}$.. I think in terms of coordinates this would translate to being a holomorphic function in some open neighbourhood of the analytic subset $X(\mathbb{C})$ in $\mathbb{C}^n,$ but not necessarily a global restriction from $\mathbb{C}^n$..?

Comment: @user141755 Let $\psi$ be a holomorphic function on $X^{an}$ which is the zero function on a dense open subset $U\subset X^{an}$. Then, as $\psi$ is holomorphic, it follows that $\psi$ is itself the zero function (on all $X^{an}$). This is called sometimes the "identity theorem", I believe. If you take $\psi$ merely continuous, then this statement is false. Think of a function which is zero on some open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ but not everywhere zero, for example.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Since $U$ is Zariski dense, it is also dense in the complex topology of $X^{an}$ and hence if $\psi$ is 0 on $U$, doesn't the mere continuity of $\psi$ imply that $\psi$ is necessarily be the zero function on all of $X^{an}$. To be completely clear, since $\psi$ is continuous $\psi^{-1}(0)$ is a closed set containing $U$ hence all of $X$ as $U$ is dense. It seems again continuity is enough for this part of the argument. I'm surely missing something :(

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar On $y^2=x^3$, the function $y/x$ extends continuously to $(0,0)$, but this extension is not holomorphic.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thank you.

Comment: When you write \text{Spec} instead of \operatorname{Spec}, the results are not always identical. With \operatorname{Spec}, the spacing to the left and right of $\operatorname{Spec}$ depends on the context, whereas with \text{Spec} you can see things like $3\text{Spec}(R)$ instead of $3\operatorname{Spec}(R),$ etc. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a noetherian integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions, and $f \in K$. Assume that for each maximal ideal $\frak m$ of $A$ the element $f \in K \subseteq K\otimes_{A}\hat{A}_{\frak m}$ is in $\hat{A}_{\frak m} \subseteq K\otimes_{A}\hat{A}_{\frak m}$ (here $\hat{A}_{\frak m}$ denotes the completion of $A$ at $\frak m$). Then $f \in A$.

Here is the proof. It is enough to show that $f \in A_{\frak m}$ for all maximal ideals $\frak m$; hence we can assume that $A$ is local. Set $\hat K = K \otimes_A \hat A$; then $\hat K$ contains both $K$ and $\hat A$, and the statement is that $A = K \cap\hat A \in \hat K$.

So, $f \in K \cap\hat A$. By the easy part of descent theory, it is enough to show that $f \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes f \in \hat A  \otimes_A \hat A$. But $f \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes f \in \hat K  \otimes_K \hat K$, because $f \in K$, and $\hat A  \otimes_A \hat A$ injects into $K \otimes_A (\hat A  \otimes_A \hat A) = \hat K  \otimes_K \hat K$.

By the way, I really don't like to interact with anonymous users, so I would appreciate it if you sent me a private email telling me who you are. You can find my email address on my homepage.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes. Ariyan Javanpeykar has contributed the hard part; here are the easy parts.

Let $\tilde{A}$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ and let $\tilde{X} = \mathrm{Spec}(\tilde{A})$. Since the map $\tilde{X} \to X$ is continuous, the pull back of $h$ to $\tilde{X}$ is a continuous function. As the OP notes, this means that $h \in \tilde{A}$. So $h$ is integral over $A$.

On the other hand, [Javanpeykar and Kucharczyk](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.09338) show that $A$ is integrally closed in the ring of holomorphic functions on $X$. We assumed that $h$ is a holomorphic function, and we have just shown that $h$ is integral over $A$. So $h \in A$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I was about to post this myself with a proof in the integrally closed case.The missing link was the integral closedness result of Javanpeykar and Kucharczyk. I would also be interested in knowing any proof that bypasses the reduction to the normal case. But for now, this is great

Comment: One can also prove this with descent theory, without reducing to the normal case. And there is a formal version, that works for any noetherian domain.

Comment: @Angelo That's a nice suggestion! Is the idea that by descent theory it suffices to prove this for some fppf (fpqc/etale) cover of $X$? Any suggestions for which covers of $X$ I should try to look at, where it would be easier to prove the result? Also, what would the statement in the formal scheme setup be?